# How do I change my PhD stipend from a private to a public one whilst keeping the same research project and owning the IP? (v2)

Tags: phd, funding, supervision, intellectual-property, australia

I'm 1 year into my PhD and don't want to be involved with the private cooperative research centre (CRC) who is funding my PhD anymore. How do I change my stipend from a private to a public one whilst keeping the same research project, direction and owning the IP?

I'm wanting to change my PhD funding from their private stipend to a public one (e.g. "RTP" scholarship) and continue the project as is without them as I don't need their input at all, don't see it's value and it would give me certainty that the IP is mine (in truth i dont care if its mine, i just don't want anyone else to stop me) and there wouldn't be any issues with me publishing my research or taking the IP further commercially if I wanted to . Now I'm wondering how I can change it over? I've already been funded by them during my first year.

Comment: Well, this version is not much shorter than the original. But regardless, my previous statement still applies: It is of course possible to decline the money you currently get; the question is where you will find someone who will replace the loss of income in the future.

Comment: Made an attempt to shorten this further. We don't need a list of all the complaints you have.

Comment: I worry about your "owning the IP". Anyone can have the same ideas that you do. Anyone can follow up on them. You can't "own" ideas, though you can have certain rights in their expression once made (copyright, patent, ...).

Comment: @buffy I've miscommunicated, what I really mean is to have the IP and to have the freedom to do what I want with it / have no else stop me. I'm fine if someone else came up with it I just don't want anyone to limit me.

Comment: @BryanKrause I disagree as I feel it added more context to the question. However, as you've already edited it, I hope I'm wrong and get more answers.